# Updating a label as a user is typing Using Cocoa-Applescript

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, applescript

I have been looking to an answer to this one for some time now. I have seen examples on how to do this outside of the Cocoa-Applescript environment, but I don't have enough knowledge to adapt this into the Applescript version.

I am trying to update a label on my UI as the user is typing in a text field. My application is a Cocoa-Applescript based app using Xcode 5.0 (this is being developed as a Mac app, not iOS).

I have tried:

```
on controlTextDidChange_(aNotification) -- a text field changed, so check it out
    set thisTextField to aNotification's object() -- the current control being changed
    set theText to thisTextField's stringValue()
    -- whatever
end controlTextDidChange_
```

But this does not seem to work for me, it only updates AFTER the user presses Enter or changes focus to another element - I need this to update AS the user is typing. I have also seen an example of this being done in an iOS app:

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textViewDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

But I have no idea how to adapt this into Applescript!

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use controlTextDidChange to accomplish this. You just need to set the delegate of your NSTextField(s) to your App Delegate object in Interface Builder, and then add something like this to your AppDelegate.applescript file:

```
property aTextField : missing value
property aTextField2 : missing value

property aTextLabel : missing value


    on controlTextDidChange_(aNotification)

       if aNotification's object() is aTextField then
           set newText to aTextField's stringValue()
           aTextLabel's setStringValue_(newText)
       end if


       if aNotification's object() is aTextField2 then
           set newText to aTextField2's stringValue()
           aTextLabel's setStringValue_(newText)
       end if

    end controlTextDidChange_
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't need any special code to do this. You do it right in the xib and with a method in your code. So create a method in your code to receive the action of the text field. Next click the xib file and select the text field in your window. In the connections section of the inspector hook the sent actions selector to the method you created. Now go to the attributes section in the inspector, and under the action drop down menu you have 2 choices; 1) sent on enter only or 2) sent on end editing. It sounds like you have the first choice selected. Try the second choice and your chosen method should get called as the user is typing.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have got 'Sent on end Editing' selected for this. But I need the method to be executed every time a key is pressed when the user is typing in the field - not just when they are finished.